# Avoid changing powershell script directory when running python virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, virtualenv

for the powershell script below

```
function jl1 {
    cd C:\Users\MyUser
    Envs\huggingface\Scripts\activate   
  
    cd "D:\Working"
    jupyter lab

}
Set-Alias jl jl1
```

I always run `jl` on my active directory

```
D:\Working123 > jl
```

Now since I do a

```
cd C:\Users\MyUser
Envs\huggingface\Scripts\activate
```

To activate my python virtual environment "huggingface", I need to explicitly set the working directory from `D:\Working` to `D:\Working123`

Is there any way to avoid changing the directory to cd `C:\Users\MyUser` to activate my python virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that work, just use the `activate.ps1` provided by the virtualenv for powershell.

```
function jl1 {
    C:\Users\TTHCMM\Envs\huggingface\Scripts\activate.ps1            
    jupyter lab

}
Set-Alias jl jl1
```